# Create a multi-level column pivot table in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

How can I create the multi-level column pivot table like below using python?
[image]

from this data frame

```
| Date     | Name   | P&L | Percentage |
|2023.1.1  | Amy    |1.1% |    2%      |
| 2023.1.1 | Peter  |1.2% |    3%      |
```

To pivot table like this

```
| Date     |      Amy         |      Peter         |
|          | P&L |Percentage  | P&L   |Percentage  | 
|2023.1.1  | 1.1%|   2%       |1.2%   |   3%       |
```

This is my previous code and seems doesn't work
result=df.pivot_table(index='Date',values=['P&L','Percentage'],columns='Name')

Answer (score 1):

Use `pivot` here as you don't have numeric data:

```
df.pivot(index='Date',values=['P&L','Percentage'],columns='Name')
```

Or `pivot_table` with `aggfunc='first'`:

```
df.pivot_table(index='Date',values=['P&L','Percentage'],columns='Name',aggfunc='first')
```

Output:

```
           P&L       Percentage      
Name       Amy Peter        Amy Peter
Date                                 
2023.1.1  1.1%  1.2%         2%    3%
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your reply. Is there any chance we could put Name in the first row (as the chart I put in my question)? I achieved this using pivot table in excel directly, but not sure how to do it in python.

Comment: @Eva do you mean `.reset_index()`?

Comment: Yes, .reset_index()may work. But how can I set the row index, eg. first row to be the name, second row to be P&L and Percentage? I guess .reset_index() is to set the column index?